# how to define images sizes to put in android toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I got put an image with this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

But the image was distorted.

There are patterns of sizes to add images in this place?

Comment: What is the size of the logo you tried? To answer your question, though, yes.  http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: icon is square, i want put an rectangular image.

Comment: Then you need a custom layout for the toolbar that contains an ImageView